# How do you find the vector $x$ determined by the given coordinate vector $[x]_B$ and basis $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the vector $x$ determined by the given coordinate vector $[x]_B$ and given basis $B$:
>   $$
>     B
>   = \left\{
>       \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ -5 \end{bmatrix},
>       \begin{bmatrix} -4 \\ 6 \end{bmatrix}
>     \right\},
>     \quad
>     [x]_B
>   = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}.
> $$

I saw a couple different ways to approach this problem from tutorials on YouTube, and each led to a different answer.  This is what I got:

```
 3    -4     |     5
-5     6     |     3

3 * 5 + -4 * 3 = 3
-5 * 5 + 6 * 3 = -7

A =    3
      -7

v1 =   3
      -5

v2 =  -4
       6

3 * v1 + -7 * v2 = x

=   9   +   28
   -15     -42

=   37
    57
```

Is that the correct answer?

Comment: So, $x=(5,3)$ is the vector in the canonical basis ($(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$) and you want to find $[x]_B$?

Comment: @Javier I believe it's the converse, based off the notation.

Comment: I see, in that case you've already answered the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is largely a matter understanding the definition and notation.  Typically if you have a basis $B=\{ \mathbf v_1,  \mathbf v_2 \}$ and are told that $[\mathbf x]_B = (x_1, x_2)$ for real numbers $x_1$, $x_2$, then $\mathbf x = x_1 \mathbf v_1 + x_2 \mathbf v_2$.  In our particular case, $$\mathbf x=5v_1 + 3v_2 = 5(3, -5) + 3(-4, 6) = (15, -25) + (-12, 18) = (3, -7) = 3 \mathbf e_1 - 7 \mathbf e_2$$ 
where $\mathbf e_1 = (1, 0)$ and $\mathbf e_2 = (0, 1)$ are the standard basis vectors for $\mathbb R^2$.